# Vaadin + SpringBoot integration and SecurityContextHolder.getContext() is null

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm using VAADIN with SpringBoot based on https://vaadin.com/spring . Things are working fine except of authentication. I'm using SpringBoot based SpringSecurity java config which works fine and  `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` returns current user for me in VaadinUI. My config is pretty straighforward here:

```
  http.authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/*").authenticated().and().httpBasic()
```

The problem is that `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` returns correct value only for the first request when VaadinUI is displayed. Then any subsequent Vaadin request (e.g. button click) returns null for SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() . Any idea how to make it work as expected?

Comment: [AFAIK](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/technical-overview.html#what-is-authentication-in-spring-security), unless you have setup [a filter to automatically do it](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/technical-overview.html#tech-intro-sec-context-persistence), you need to store the authentication info by calling `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(…​)`

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the way Vaadin handles the requests. It does not use DispatcherServlet, and you probably need to use RequestContextListener (or RequestContextFilter) to enable request and session scopes.

Have a look [discussion about a related topic here](https://vaadin.com/wiki?p_p_id=36&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=row-1&p_p_col_pos=1&p_p_col_count=3&p_r_p_185834411_title=I%20b%20-%20Getting%20started%20with%20Vaadin%20Spring%20without%20Spring%20Boot&p_r_p_185834411_nodeName=vaadin.com%20wiki&_36_struts_action=%2Fwiki%2Fview&_36_delta=20&_36_keywords=&_36_advancedSearch=false&_36_andOperator=true&p_r_p_564233524_resetCur=false&_36_cur=3).

Comment: Hmm, I can't find any complete example how to do it. I need to access SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() or should I copy getAuthentication()  object and store it into initial ApplicationUI object?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your @Configuration class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is annotated with `@EnableWebSecurity`.